# Adding Data file to existing SQL server Always on Database

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

Wanted to know if its ok to add additional data file (.ndf file) to existing database which is configured in always on availability group?
Is it recommended to do during downtime?
The databases which need additional file are very big (2TB to 5TB). The new file will be added to different disk from the rest of the data files on that database. Please advise if I can add the data file through GUI on primary replica server in production environment without downtime? Secondary server has same disks and folder paths. Will there be any issues which I need to be careful? Thank you

Comment: If the path of new file exists in all secondary replica , there is nothing to worry about. Otherwise the secondary replica state changes to NOT SYNCRONIZED.

Comment: Thank you Meyssam, so can i add the files without any downtime in production environment?

Comment: If you are going to add an empty file using ADD FILE statement then yes. But there is one thing. Creating a big size file can take some time especially when SERVICE ACCOUNT user has not granted "Perform volume maintenance task privilege". So first of all check service account has granted that permission.